# html table, getting text value of first column relative to the row I clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a table and i  am trying to get the value of the first column based on the row I clicked.
I tried this

```
$("#divid").on("click", ".tableid", function(){

  alert($(this).find('td:first').text());

});
```

But it always gives me the first row and first column of my table. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are selecting the table ".tableid" instead of the clicked row, so the further reference $(this) will be the whole table instead of the clicked row. You have to replace ".tableid" with ".tableid tr".

Here's the correct example https://jsfiddle.net/nf76rxyq/2/

Html

```
<div id="divid">
    <table class="tableid">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divid").on("click", ".tableid tr", function() {
        alert($(this).find('td:first').text());
    });
});
```